# Node Application Only Properly Serving 1 out of 2 Images in Same Subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been scouring SO for a bit trying to find something similar using **just** node following a text book example from my course. I understand that it would probably be easier to utilize express or a similar tool to use as my static resource server, though at the moment I am doing it this way to learn and better understand what is going on. I am sure it's something simple I'm likely overlooking, but any help to identify the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

I have a simple createServer function that looks like

**createServer**

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
  // normalize url by removing querystring, optional trailing slash, and
  // making lowercase
  const path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '').toLowerCase()
  switch(path) {
    case '':
      serveStaticFile(res, '/public/home.html', 'text/html')
      break
    case '/about':
      serveStaticFile(res, '/public/about.html', 'text/html')
      break
    case '/public/img/warm-urge.jpg':
      serveStaticFile(res, '/public/img/warm-urge.jpg', 'image/jpg')
      break
    case '/public/img/timessquareColor.jpg':
      serveStaticFile(res, '/public/img/timessquareColor.jpg', 'image/jpg')
      break
    default:
      serveStaticFile(res, '/public/404.html', 'text/html', 404)
      break
  }
})
```

With a serve file function that looks like

**serveStaticFile**

```
function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode = 200) {
  //readFile is an asynchronous method for reading files.
  //__dirname will resolve to the directory the executing script resides in.

  fs.readFile(__dirname + path, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
      return res.end('500 - Internal Error')
    }
    res.writeHead(responseCode, { 'Content-Type': contentType })
    res.end(data)
  })
}
```

When I run this on local host, the image '/public/img/warm-urge.jpg' is served without issue and the image is seen fine on my page. However, the image '/public/img/timessquareColor.jpg' has a few issues. When I hit the page in localhost, I receive a 404 for the image not being found, but the content type is shown as 'text/html' as the screenshot shows below.

**EDIT** I realize now that it's likely sent as text/html since that is the content type I set for 404. With that being said, I know my root problem is that node is not serving the one file, though my confusion comes in searching for the "why?" as I do the exact same thing for both images (to my limited knowledge) but only one cooperates effectively

[image]

I know I am attempting to serve it as content type 'image/jpg' , but it does not quite seem to hit the mark. I also verified i am calling them both the same way in my html as such

**index.html snippet**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 id="topOfPage" class="display-1 text-center" style="font-size:50px">Home Page</h1>     
    <p>Hello World Landing Page</p> 
    <p>this is the landing page for my node app using azure.</p>
    <img src="/public/img/warm-urge.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
</div>
<br>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p>This photo was taken in Times Square, NYC in 2019.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <img src="/public/img/timessquareColor.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="times square">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case statement has an uppercase letter in it:

```
case '/public/img/timessquareColor.jpg':
```

But your code forces everything to lowercase so they will never match:

```
const path = req.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)?$/, '').toLowerCase()
```

---

Change the case statement to all lowercase:

```
case '/public/img/timessquarecolor.jpg':
```

Comment: Thank you! That was precisely it, I was too engrossed in how I was serving it and looking at the request I completely overlooked the case for finding said image. I really appreciate it thanks again!